# Switch classes after use .addClass on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some problem right now with this: http://jsfiddle.net/jalxob/WkWyc/1/

```
$(".show_hide").addClass( "hola1" );
```

The "show" link is in green and when I click on it to show the div it turns yellow, but when I click it again to hide the div the "show" link stills in yellow.

Is there any way to turn it as green (the default class)?

Thank you so much!

Comment: [`$(".show_hide").toggleClass("hola2");`](http://jsfiddle.net/gQ77w/)

Comment: Hint: When you use JSFIDDLE, use the sidebar options to add libraries instead of adding it to the javascript window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use jQuery's [**`toggleClass()`**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) method instead of `addClass()` to achieve this.

```
$(".show_hide").toggleClass("hola2");
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/WkWyc/4/)

Comment: Youre fiddle's javascript is incorrect, use [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/WkWyc/4/), I revised it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing addClass("hola2") on your click. Do toggleClass("hola2").

This will remove the class if it is there or add the class if not.